# rspec testing a controller method, calling a lib wrapper that makes an API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In the application, the user can fill in 3 fields (and 1 hidden field) and click 'load response', and this will make an ajax API call to an external API. The call to the external API is in a wrapper in lib. This wrapper stores additional required fields that the user doesn't need to enter, but are required by the API.

I've seen a few other posts about testing API calls, but I'm stumped on comparing them to this one and learning something from it, because of that extra wrapper.

**What would a test look like, to test this API, based on the system's architecture?**

In the view:

```
data = ->
  string_ssid = '#{@bar.ssID}'
  {
    approval_code: $('#approval_code').val()
    rejection_code: $('#rejection_code').val()
    rejection_message: $('#rejection_message').val()
    ssid: string_ssid
  }

ajax_call = ->
  $('#load_response').on 'click', ->
    $.ajax
      url: '/fooview/api_response'
      data: data()
      success: (d) ->
        $('#api_response').html '<p>' + JSON.stringify(d) + '</p>'
        return
      error: (d, status, e) ->
        $('#api_response').html '<p>Error: ' + e + ', ' + status + '</p>'
        return
    return
  return
```

Routes:

```
get '/baz/api_response', to: 'baz#api_response'
```

Controller:

```
  def api_response
    render json: BazWrapper.get_api_response(params)
  end
```

Wrapper:

```
module BazWrapper

  @base_url = Enviro.get(:foo) + '/message/json'

  def self.get_api_response(params)

    query_values = {
    api_key: Enviro.get(:foo, :api_key),
    approval_code: params[:approval_code],
    rejection_code: params[:rejection_code],
    rejection_message: params[:rejection_message],
    ssid: params[:ssid],
    (..other required params hard-wired..)
  }

  HTTParty.post(
    URI.encode(@base_url),
    query: query_values
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking.

Comment: Added a sentence to clarify what I'm asking :)

Answer (score 0):

I would test this at a high level using a feature spec, and also a unit test for the wrapper module.

To help with testing and to stop requests hitting the real API I would use the WebMock gem (https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). With this gem you will be able to stub requests and set the response and status code.

A feature spec using RSpec/Capybara would look something like -

```
RSpec.feature 'loads response from Baz', type: :feature do
  scenario 'response if success' do
    stub_request(:any, 'www.example.com').
      to_return(:body => 'blah', :status => 200)

    visit '/my-url'

    fill_in '#approval_code', with: '123'
    # ... fill in other fields ...

    click_button 'Load Response'

    # check the page contains whatever you expect as the stringified JSON
    expect(page).to have_content('blah')
  end

  # then test the failure scenario
end
```

You can take this further and write a spec to test that your wrapper requests the correct URL with the expected params.

Using WebMock again you can set expectations on the WebMock module and verify the last request.

e.g.

```
describe BazWrapper do
  describe '.get_api_response' do
    let(params) {
      {
        approval_code: 'x'
      }
    }

    before do
      stub_request(:any, 'www.example.com').
        to_return(:body => 'blah', :status => 200)
    end

    it 'requests the data' do
      BazWrapper.get_api_response(params)

      expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:post, 'www.example.com').
        with(query: { approval_code: 'x' })
    end
  end
end
```